# Evolution doesn't work after copying system to a new disk - not connecting, seems to be a password issue

Tags: password, evolution

I use Evolution 3.36.5-0ubuntu1 in Kubuntu 20.04 to do my mail traffic. It worked all fine besides of some irritating asking for passwords sometimes. I deactivated the KDE password manager kde wallet and it was better then.

After migrating to a new harddisk, Evolution asked for keyring password at least ten times, then it worked properly for 2 days. Now it won't connect anymore. I suppose it's some issue with the gnome keyring but I don't know...

I used the `dd` command to migrate my whole system to a new disk:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc
```

Same os, same installation. I had some trouble with UUIDs and lost the configuration files of my file manager program but now all is working fine like before. Except the mail program Evolution that seems to have a password issue.

I don't use auto login.

In `/home/sebigbos/.local/share/keyrings/` there are 5 files named:
`login.keyring`:

```
Standard-Schlüsselbund.keyring
Standard-Schlüsselbund_1.keyring
Standard-Schlüsselbund_2.keyring
Standard-Schlüsselbund_3.keyring
```

The latter 3 of them have date and time that Evolution stopped working. Can I delete them?

The 2nd one seems to contain audio program configuring data - that's quite weird.

Answer (score -1):

okeee....

It's working now.

I deleted the files

Standard-Schlüsselbund.keyring

Standard-Schlüsselbund_1.keyring

Standard-Schlüsselbund_2.keyring

Standard-Schlüsselbund_3.keyring

Then I had to enter the mail-passwords once again in Evolution and system asked if it schould save it in the keyring, I said yes.

After restarting the system the problem was there again and I realized that the new file "Standard-Schlüsselbund.keyring" had the rights -rw------. I changed it to -rw-rw-rw- and entered the mail passwords again in Evolution.
After doing this file rights were again -rw-----, but it's working now anyway.

I only have to enter keyring-password once after starting the system then I use Evolution the first time in the session. This behaviour I had before the system change also and I can live with it.

Sorry, this is a mess but perhaps somebody can use it.

ps: I lost a few newer passwords in Brave browser. For example the one to askubuntu...;)

Comment: making the keyring file writable for everyone seems like a really insecure idea - better have it as `-rw-r--r--` (644 in octal) I expect that would still work fine.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this.